# Multicurrency on an encryption org

Tags: encryption, multi-currency

So on a normal org you have to update SOQL queries to use 'convertCurrency (field) alias' for any Currency field you want to get.

Is the same thing required for SOSL or is there a different way of doing it on an encrypted org?

In Apex I get

```
unexpected syntax: 'extraneous input 'testValue' expecting RPAREN'
```

I cant seem to alias my convertCurrency use in the FIND, even though it says I can here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_querying_currency_fields.htm

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question. Are you asking about SOQL versus SOSL, Platform Encryption versus non-encryption, or both? Can you add an example query or use case via [edit] to be specific?

Comment: I want to know how you run a multi currency query in SOSL.

Comment: Updated my original post with more information

Comment: I don't see any indication that SOSL supports aliasing the result of `convertCurrency()`; the error you're seeing appears to suggest it does not.

Comment: If you go to that link and then on the menu on the left go to Salesforce Object Query Language (SOQL), open that and go to convertCurrency(). At the bottom it explains that it does. It gives an example: FIND {Acme} RETURNING Account(AnnualRevenue, convertCurrency(AnnualRevenue) AliasCurrency)

Comment: Okay. it works exactly as I have it. It just doesnt seem to work in Eclipse. Christ.

Comment: if it is not working in eclipse, verify the API version used by your Eclipse IDE. Since this IDE is no longer supported, you might want to consider upgrading to VS Code, Illuminated Cloud or Welkin Suite IDEs